# Delete featured image for WP posts older than date

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a WP site where I want to remove featured images of all posts older than a given date.

I don't want to remove the actual image files from the server. Only looking to remove the postmeta fields for featured images on posts older than X date.

Did some searching around and found this code.

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query( "
   DELETE FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
   WHERE meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
" );
```

**It remove featured images on all posts. I want to run it for only old posts. How do I modify it to fit my need?**

Comment: you should add which column is date and what is considered old

Comment: The date isn't in the `post_meta` fields. The date is in `posts` you'll have to join or do a loop.

Comment: How do I join wp_posts date ? And if the site has too many posts, will it crash the server?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be simpler to edit your template to not display those older images? In this scenario you have to check post's publishing date and if the post is older than Xdate don't display the thumbnail image. Simple.

Comment: Actually, I want to remove featured images for older posts because Currently it is showing broken image, and I want to remove it and then add the correct image again.

Comment: So if you want to add other images anyway - the easiest is to go to certain posts and replace images in admin screen of this particular post. Click 'remove thumbnail' and add a new one.